# How to remove the tick number in tikzpicture code?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-cd

I created the code of tikzpicture in Geogebra. I want to remove the tick number leaving only the ticks. How to modify the code and remove the tick number. The code of the tick picture is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,
axis lines=middle,
xmin=-0.9,
xmax=4.3,
ymin=-0.8,
ymax=4.8,
xtick={-0.0,1.0,...,4.0},
ytick={-0.0,1.0,...,4.0},]
\draw [->,line width=1.pt] (-0.94,0.58) -- (3.66,4.32);
\draw [line width=1.pt] (1.032939261855717,2.1840853998566048)-- (1.,0.);
\draw [line width=1.pt] (3.042000477984272,3.817539519056778)-- (3.,0.);
\draw [line width=1.pt] (1.032939261855717,2.1840853998566048)-- (3.0244214305585078,2.219731316008284);
\draw (0.5839577167019019,2.863133192389007) node[anchor=north west] {$\text P$};
\draw (2.461336152219873,4.486811839323468) node[anchor=north west] {$\text Q$};
\draw (0.7361775898520077,-0.01213107822410112) node[anchor=north west] {$x_1$};
\draw (2.8672558139534883,-0.07978435517970366) node[anchor=north west] {$x_2$};
\draw (0.6516109936575044,1.4762410147991547) node[anchor=north west] {$y_1$};
\draw (3.104042283298097,1.696114164904863) node[anchor=north west] {$y_2$};
\draw (3.1378689217758984,3.455099365750529) node[anchor=north west] {$y_2-y_1$};
\draw (1.514190274841437,2.3219069767441867) node[anchor=north west] {$x_2-x_1$};
\draw (4.304887949260042,0.3430486257928122) node[anchor=north west] {$x$};
\draw (-0.14331501057082555,5.298651162790699) node[anchor=north west] {$y$};
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=black] (1.032939261855717,2.1840853998566048) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (1.,0.) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (3.042000477984272,3.817539519056778) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (3.,0.) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (3.0244214305585078,2.219731316008284) circle (2.5pt);
\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to add this

```
xticklabels=\empty,
yticklabels=\empty,
```

after the last comma in `ytick={-0.0,1.0,...,4.0},` and before the `]`in line 10